# AttributeError: 'Hundo' object has no attribute 'saluti'

Tags: python-3.x

I am triying to access to the atribute of Animalo's class with the subclasses, but it did not work, I have checked indentation.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

class Animalo:
    """ Klaso bazo por montri la apanagxo"""

    def __init__(self, nomo, kruroj):
        self.nomo = nomo
        self.kruroj = kruroj

    def saluti(self):
            print("La animalo nomigxi: " + str(self.nomo) + " Salutas")
class Hundo(Animalo):
    """Klaso filino por montri la apanagxo"""

    def boji(self):
        print("Boj Boj")

class Kato(Animalo):
    """Klaso bazo por montri la apanagxo"""

    def miaui(self):

        print("Miaux miaux")
            
mia_maskoto = Hundo("Perro", 4)

mia_maskoto.saluti()

mia_maskoto.boji()

mia_alia_maskoto = Kato("Gato", 4)

mia_alia_maskoto.saluti()

mia_alia_maskoto.miaui()
```

I removed the line mia_maskoto.saluti() and mia_alia_maskoto.saluti() and the code does not output any errors

Comment: You should probably check your indentation once again ;-) If you decrease the indent for `def saluti(self):`, all works fine.

Comment: It worked, it was the def saluti(self)